# A method to obtain the OxyPlot tooltip content in variables

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I have in a Windows Forms Application, an OxyPlot scatter plot. The default tip displays the value of the point I am having my mouse down on, but I cannot manage to obtain those values in a variable, or the variable that stores those values, in order to do other methods.

I have tried "overwritting" the tooltip, by unbinding and binding the mouse down event, it seemed that it stayed with the initial tooltip, I have tried converting from screen points to plot values, but I was not able to obtain points at all.
The need for the tooltip content comes from the need of handling the data; the points on the scatter plot are actual peak values of measurements, and as an entry I also have the file name of each point (name that I managed to add in the default tooltip of the oxyplot), and on the click of a point I need to open the file (behavior which I managed to obtain with Windows Forms). If I could find a way to even display I message box with the content of the tool tip, I would have a way to solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.